# Analyzing data to determine seasonal indices?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, descriptive-statistics

The quarterly sales levels for the past four years of a leading tyre manufacturer are displayed on the table

[image: Statistics]

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cszy.png)

How to analyze the data to determine the specific seasonal indices,and what conclusion can be deduced from the results?

Generally after $Q2$(second quarter) i notice a slight decrease in manufacturing ,which implies the relationship is not linear,and also with the average production for each season being respectively $2397,2623,2537,2645$,

i would like to know **how further this data can be analyzed** and how to obtain sales for the next quarter of 2013(assuming that cyclical and irregular components are negligible)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what type of analysis you want/need to do. One thing you may do is to do a linear regression analysis on the sales of each quarter $Q_1,..,Q_4$, and from the model for each $Q_i$, extrapolate into $2013$. There are other techniques you can use, like $ANOVA$ , where you test whether the means for sales in different quarters are different at a given significance level. Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.